# Jackson merging json array

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, jackson

I have the following Jsons:

```
{"loc":[{"b":3}]}
```

and

```
{"loc":[{"a":9}]}
```

How can I use Jackson 2.9.0 to merge them into

```
{"loc":[{"a":9, "b":3}]}
```

This is what I have so far

```
public class Config {
    @JsonMerge
    public AB[] loc;
}

@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class AB {
    public Integer a;
    public Integer b;

    protected AB() { }
    public AB(int a0, int b0) {
        a = a0;
        b = b0;
    }
}

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

config = mapper.readValue(aposToQuotes("{'loc':[{'b':3}]}"), Config.class);
config = mapper.readerForUpdating(config).readValue(aposToQuotes("{'loc':[{'a':9}]}"));
```

The result is

```
{"loc":[{"b":3},{"a":9}]}
```

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Please check my edited post. Thank you

Answer (score -1):

firstly, you can will json convertTo List and merge List, then will List convertTo json.